# WhatsApp re-registration after backup

Tags: backup, titanium-backup, whatsapp-messenger

I want to flash a custom rom on my S3. I was wondering if I take a Titanium Backup of all the applications and data on my phone, would I need to re-register (sim verification) for applications like WhatsApp, Tango, Viber etc. even after I restore the data?

Comment: I wouldn't put my hands in the fire for that -- but as TB backs up all the apps data, I'd say a proper restore would look to the app as if nothing happened, so you would not need to re-register. At least not if IMEI/IMSI/... stay unchanged (I don't know what they check) and your Google Account etc. stays the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I played with fire and went ahead and backed up my data with TB, flashed a custom rom (ParanoidAndroid 3.0) and restored the backup! Well, this is how it went:

- **WhatsApp** - restored the data without re-registration
- **Tango** - re-register
- **Viber** - restored
- **Google+** - log in required and configure the settings
- **Facebook** - already logged in (but re-sync contacts)
- **Path** - already logged in

Answer (score 4):

When you flash a custom rom and you are coming from different version of android, **restoring app data may cause some problems**. If you restore your **Whatsapp's data may cause crashing that App**. So its better not to backup data,backup just that Application. If you are flashing same android version it may not cause issues. And you don't need to re-register.